# How to identify a specific row from a custom listview once a button has been clicked

Tags: android, xml, listview, button

I am new to android development and am trying to create a multi-columned list view with a button at the end of each row. I have the following xml to implement this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value_name"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/child_name"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/point_value"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"   />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/claimChore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text = "Claim Chore"/>
```

I have been searching online for an answer to this problem and found a solution to add to the code. However, this solution's button wasn't tailored to find information about the specific row and so I don't know what to place inside this method to retrieve this. If anyone could shed some light on what to place in this onClick method it would be a great help.

```
 wrapper.mySimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(Child_Chore.this, chores, R.layout.list_format, new String[]{"chore","points"},new int[]{R.id.value_name,R.id.point_value})
                {
                    @Override
                    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                    {
                        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                        Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.claimChore);
                        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                               //Where I want to identify the current R.id.value_name;
                            }
                        });
                        return v;
                    }


                };
```

Comment: set the onItemClickListener in the listView and identify with listView.get(position).getButtonID

Comment: As I said I am new to android development, could you please make it clearer what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable 'position', that the method 'getView' give to you.

```
@Override
                public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.claimChore);
                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                           //Where I want to identify the current 
                            doAnything(position);
                        }
                    });
                    return v;
                }
```